# youtube api - get most subscribed gaming channels in poland

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

My goal is to obtain most subscribed gaming channels in Poland.
I've created request like

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelType=any&q=gaming&regionCode=pl&relevanceLanguage=pl&topicId=%2Fm%2F0bzvm2&type=channel HTTP/1.1`

And I obtained some channels. Then I used this request to obtain information about subscription count of 1 of obtained channels:

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&part=statistics&id=UCkHooOtMNRCc54XFKBAisdg HTTP/1.1`

I received a result like

`"viewCount": "15317994", "subscriberCount": "115000", "videoCount": "211"` which is correct.

What problem do I have? Just few:

1. How to retrieve top gaming channels in poland ordered by subscription using one request?
2. When I remove gaming from query then I retrieve not only Polish channels, why?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How to retrieve top gaming channels in poland ordered by subscription using one request?

If the first request you made (*i.e. `search`*) brings you the channels you need, then, get those `channel_id` and separate such channels in comma, then, use the second call (*i.e `channels`*) for retrieve the statistics of those comma-separated `channel_id`.

Check the documentation of the API, if I recall correctly, the `channel_id` parameter has a limit of 50 `channel_id`.

---

About your second question:

> 2. When I remove gaming from query then I retrieve not only Polish channels, why?

That cannot be answered here, IMHO, you haven't provide enough information for compare the data you got and only YouTube knows how its API works inside.